# Session is getting overwritten in Java

Tags: java, session

I am facing a strange issue:

I have a page with an email field in it when I submit the page the control goes to a servlet where I am saving the email value in session by using

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("email_Value", request.getParameter("email_Value"));
```

Now, on the basis of this email value I lookup the database and extracts the information for this user if information found then remove the session attribute by

```
request.getSession().removeAttribute("email_Value");
```

if not then redirect the request to same page with an error message and prefilled email value which I am extracting from session using

```
if(null!= request.getSession().getAttribute("email_Value")){
            String Email = (String)(request.getSession().getAttribute("email_Value"));
            request.getSession().removeAttribute("email_Value");            
    }
```

It works fine on our deleopment, UAT environments but problem is coming only on PROD where we have load balancer.

The issue is that while coming back to the same page it change the email address field witch some different email value which I have not even entered on my machine i.e. it is accessing someone else session.

Could someone provide any pointer to resolve this issue. As this is Production issue, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.Distributable) may help you

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to use sticky-sessions. This must be configured in the apache

Answer (score 0):

`Http` is a `stateless` protocol meaning, the server doesnt know to identify a client over a period of time. 
When a client makes a call to the server (load balanced, say server_1 & server_2), it could reach either `server_1` or `server_2`, assume the request reaches the `server_1`, now your `code` creates a `session` and adds the `email` to the session.
When the same client makes another call to the server, this time it hits `server_2`, the `email` which is in `server_1` session is not available to `server_2` and `server_2` might have `email` from another `session` thats why you are seeing another `email` address.
Hope its clear.

[Solution:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740860/http-session-tracking)

1. URL Rewriting
2. Cookies

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in our application we also have login functionality where the entire user DTO object is saved in session and accessing the values from registration to login or update profile page. We are not doing anything different there and still it is working. ALso do you think any pass by reference or something like that is causing issue.

Comment: Moreover, if my request is coming to server 2 then ideally it should not get any value infact it should be the new session for server 2 but it is getting value from session which is probably created by some other user from different machine.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is deployed on multiple servers, chances are there that your sessions may get transferred between servers. Also, in such scenarios, if you are storing any objects in sessions, they HAVE TO implement `Serializable` interface. If they don't, then the data will not be persisted when the session gets migrated.

Also, it seems that the session gets interchanged with another one. Are you storing anything at Application level?
I would also advice you to look into [HttpSessionActivationListener](http://www.xyzws.com/Servletfaq/when-do-i-use-httpsessionactivationlistener/4) for your case.

Comment: Also, please make sure that you aren't storing anything in instance variables of `servlet`. Everything has to be manipulated by local variables.

Comment: Could you elaborate more that how and where do I need to implement Serializable interface.

Comment: All the user defined objects being put in session as attribute have to implement Serializable. UserDTO in your case I believe.

Comment: I am doing exactly the same way, I have mentioned in the code snippet above. Do you see any problem in that or do you want me to initialize session variable first like HttpSession session = request.getSession(); and then set the attribute.

Comment: Yes, I just checked that User DTO object implements Serializable, what can I do for this single email field?

Comment: I believe you are using `request.getSession(boolean)` in your application. `getSession()` will always give you a new session. Read this -> http://www.coderanch.com/t/364672/Servlets/java/request-getSession-request-getSession-boolean

Comment: No I am not using request.getSession(boolean), and if getSession will always return new session then in my case I should always get blank value but instead I am getting value that too from different session object. I am still not clear what changes do I need to make to overcome this issue.

Comment: Are you storing email id or any other value in static/instance variable in any class.

Comment: No I am not storing any value in static instance just saving directly to session and fetching from session.

Comment: I am directly setting request.getParameter in session, do you think it can have any impact?

Comment: Hello All, please let me know some solution

Comment: May I know which load balancer you are using? Also, which server you are using?

Comment: We have 2 tomcat servers on PROD...the strange thing is that we are using other variables too in session which are not object but simply string variables. However there we have taken the value from request through request.getParameter() and assigning it to local variable and that local variable we are setting in session. however here I am directly setting request.getParameter()....can this be the issue

Comment: It doesn't cause any issue if the request parameter is retrieved into local variable before being set into session or not. 
However, it seems there is something wrong in the application itself rather than server configuration. Are you accessing session in scriptlet on JSP? Can you post the code where you are setting and getting this session attribute?
Also, see this link -> http://www.coderanch.com/t/482072/Tomcat/Session-Crossover-Tomcat